# Turing machine that adds two decimal numbers

Tags: state-machine, finite-automata, computation-theory, turing-machines

I'm having trouble conceptualizing how I would start solving this problem. 
I was able to create a Turing machine that adds two unary, and two binary numbers.

I have a general idea of how to solve this problem:

While first number > 0:
Decrement first number.
Increment the second number.

How do you actually decrement a decimal number?

Comment: I was able to solve it

Comment: Please post in the answer. Others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This way, we can add two numbers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).